# How to change the internal vim python sys.path?

Tags: vimscript-python, vim9

I have learned that `py3eval('print(sys.path)')` return the `sys.path` used internally by `Vim`.

Say that i want add a `new_path` to the current `sys.path`. How shall I do?

I would appreciate solutions that work with `Vim9`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do:

```
:py sys.path.append('new_path')
```